# Get default value of an input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, default-value

```
$(".box_yazi2").each(function () {
    var default_value = this.value;
    $(this).css('color', '#555'); // this could be in the style sheet instead
    $(this).focus(function () {
        if (this.value == default_value) {
            this.value = '';
            $(this).css('color', '#000');
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function () {
        if (this.value == '') {
            $(this).css('color', '#555');
            this.value = default_value;
        }
    });
});
```

This function of default value of input doesnt work in FF, but perfectly works in IE
and ofcourse the input itself looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class="box_yazi2" id="konu" name="konu" value="Boş" />
```

Comment: Why don't you use `this.defaultValue`?

Comment: The last line is an extra set of `});`. Is this just incorrectly copy-pasted?

Comment: @venom Well, it works in Fx [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/J6hTk/).

Comment: does Firebug return an error of some kind maybe? Also, if you just want to get this done (and don't do it for learning purpose): http://mucur.name/system/jquery_example/

Comment: @Box9 yeah ) it is the last function in document.ready )) @jensgram I will try it thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is quite easy; you have an extra `});` in your code (thanks @ Box9).

I would encourage you to reuse the variable and not create dozens of jQuery objects.

I've changed your example to `background-color` but it will work.

```
$('.box_yazi2').each(function(index, element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var defaultValue = $element.val();
    $element.css('background-color', '#555555');
    $element.focus(function() {
        var actualValue = $element.val();
        if (actualValue == defaultValue) {
            $element.val('');
            $element.css('background-color', '#3399FF');
        }
    });
    $element.blur(function() {
        var actualValue = $element.val();
        if (!actualValue) {
            $element.val(defaultValue);
            $element.css('background-color', '#555555');
        }
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nBYLP/)

Answer (score 81):

Just use the [**`defaultValue`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-26091157) property:

```
var default_value = $(this).prop("defaultValue");
```

Or:

```
var default_value = this.defaultValue;
```

Comment: you should elaborate your example. currently there's no attribute `defaultValue`

Comment: defaultValue is a built-in attribute accessible via JavaScript. For input[type=text], it contains the original value of the input element... the value that was present when the page was loaded.

Comment: NICE!  I had no idea.  Is this attribute widely supported/accessible in this manner?

Comment: @crazy: See [Interface HTMLInputElement as described in DOM level 2 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025) and [HTMLInputElement on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement). Other interesting attributes are defaultChecked and defaultSelected for radio/checkboxes and options inside select element.

Comment: .attr('defaultValue') does not work in jQuery, as attr calls upon the HTML Attributes.

Comment: @Navarr: it used to work when I posted this answer. I've revised the answer for current version of jQuery.

Comment: There's a diff between attributes and properties in HTML. for getting the defaultValue or defaultChecked, we should use the .prop() method. There's a good explanation at jQuery.com: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus( function(){
            elementValue = $(this).val();
            $(this).val("");
        });
        $('input[type="text"]').blur( function(){
            if($(this).val() != elementValue && $(this).val() != ""){

            }else{
                $(this).val(elementValue);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the next code:

```
    //clear the focused inputs
$('input[type="text"]').focus( function(){
    if( $(this).attr('value') == $(this).attr('defaultValue') ){
        $(this).attr('value', '');
    };
} );
$('input[type="text"]').blur( function(){
    if( $(this).attr('value') == '' ){
        $(this).attr('value', $(this).attr('defaultValue') );
    };
} );
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `.attr('value', ...)` but `.val(...)` to change an element's value!

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.defaultValue`

Sorry for the link to w3notcools, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp

Comment: w3schools is a [horrible resource](http://w3fools.com). A better reference would be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement#Properties

Comment: ThiefMaster, I learned a lot thanks to w3schools and I can't share your view of it being 'horrible resource'. Just because there are better and more detailed or more advanced resources than mentioned website, it doesn't make one 'horrible'. Also, the fact that they don't have anything with the W3C or that someone created a website to bash them - doesn't mean anything regarding their 'horribleness'.
To tell the truth - W3C themselves had so much awful solutions/decisions that they are the last to bash other people/companies.

Comment: @userfuser http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Answer (score 0):

You should use prop instead of so many functions to be honest, use 'delegate' instead of 'on' for late static binding.

```
$('.box_yazi2').each(function() {

$(this).on('focus', function(){

   if($(this).val() == $(this).prop('defaultValue')){

      $(this).val('');
      $(this).css('color', '#000');
    }

});

$(this).on('blur', function(){

   if($(this).val() == ''){

      $(this).val($(this).prop('defaultValue'));
      $(this).css('color', '#000');
   }

});

});
```