# How to avoid multiple event listeners on a text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am making a application using Backbone Marionette. In which I need to observe and update the model on each of the text fields.

so, I used the following concept:

```
$("#textbox").on('keyup  paste focus focusout', function() {
    console.log('I am pretty sure the text box changed');
});
```

But the problem is, when a person paste some value to text box, I am getting the console 3 times or more. - how to suspend the 3 console? (it's all triggering same time keyup, focus, past)

Again is it good practice to use number of listener with a single text box? I am wondering the approach is correct or not about?

Is there any listener which taking care of anything happening with text box?

Or any good practice please?

using input as well make this type of issues too..

[jQuery Input Event does not Fire if Input is Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004581/jquery-input-event-does-not-fire-if-input-is-empty)

Thanks In advance.

[Here is the Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/w42AS/)

Comment: You can replace `keyup paste` by `input`. Not sure about `focus` and `blur/focusout`

Comment: Use `unbind` and then `bind` to avoid multiple listeners instead of using `on`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can listen any number of events with a single text box.

```
$("#textbox").on('keyup  paste focus focusout', function(e) {
    switch(e.type) {
        case  "keyup":
            console.log('keyup');        
        break;

        case  "paste":
            console.log('paste');        
        break;

        case  "focus":
            console.log('focus');        
        break;

        case  "focusout":
            console.log('focusout');        
        break;    
    }

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JUu75/)

Comment: Still all are triggering, but Helps me to find some workarounds..  thanks

Comment: this is the way if you use multiple event with same listener function, otherwise you have to add different listener function for each event (single event bind to single listener).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w42AS/1/)**

```
$("#textbox").on('input focus focusout', function() {
    console.log('I am pretty sure the text box changed');
});
```

- You can have a common **[input](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#event-input-input)** event instead of `keyup` and `paste`.
- You can also implement `change` event, but it has some time lag before it is fired.

**[Input event Browser support](http://danielfriesen.name/blog/2010/02/16/html5-browser-maze-oninput-support/)**

Comment: Agree, But which is not working properly with old browsers..? I am working including ie6.

Comment: Added the browser support link. IE9- does not support input

Answer (score 0):

Are you [asking the right question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

I think you are likely really asking

"How do I know if a field has changed" which is partly answered here: [Get default value of an input using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591889/get-default-value-of-an-input-using-jquery)

The second part (the paste part) can be handled by adding the `input` event handler as answered by @shaunakde or if there is an issue, run a setInterval on focus and clearInterval on focusout

Answer (score 0):

for any property that changes on the `#textbox` element, not just the value property.

```
   jQuery('#textbox').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
        // do your stuff
    });
```